# Start Flyway migration from specific version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, flyway

I try use **flyway** for migration. I find this option

> spring.flyway.target= # Target version up to which migrations should
>   be considered.

But I need set version with which to start migration. For exmple I need start migration from `V3_foo.sql`

Can I do it?

Briefly why I need it. I have a database with data. No migration tools have been used before. Everything was done manually. Now I have created an `init.sql` and placed in it the creation of the entire base structure. Now, when adding changes, I will start the migration from version 2. And if you need to run on a new empty database - from version 1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Baseline](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/flyway-cli-and-api/usage/command-line/command-line-baseline) is the flyway feature you need.

If your case, `baseline` your database with `flyway.baselineVersion=2` will tell flyway that your database is already at the version 2. Any subsequent `flyway migrate` will only process migrations greater than 2.

Note: If previous migrations failed, it may be necessary to drop table `flyway_schema_history` first.

Comment: Yes, I already read about it but this option not work for me. `spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
spring.flyway.baseline-version=2
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true` - I add thos configs. And I have empty `flyway_schema_history` table. When I start server I get error - `Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.FlywaySqlScriptException: 
Migration V1__Initial_version.sql failed`

Comment: I wait that flayway skip V1 and start migration from V2. But it start from V1

Comment: write in your answer that it is necessary that the table `flyway_schema_history ` does not exist and I will accept your answer

Comment: @ip696 Maybe a repair would have done the job... Answer updated anyway.